# Backbone: display returned models in a different collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using the `where` method grab some specific models from a collection. Similar to the example from backbone site:

```
var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Guard"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});
```

Which will return the 2 models that has the Musketeer job.

How do I put those 2 Musketeer models into a new collection and render a collectionView for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it to a new collection using `collection.reset`.  Then simply pass it to a view and render.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#container",

    template: _.template($("#templ").html()),

    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(model) {
            self.$el.append(self.template(model.toJSON()));
        });
    }        
});

var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Guard"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});

var newCollection = new Backbone.Collection();
newCollection.reset(musketeers);

var view = new MyView({ collection: newCollection });
view.render();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3JEz/1/

Comment: Awesome! One more question. How would you go about using this concept but, using "where" inside of an array that a attribute has? Example: job: [MuskNewbie, MuskPro, MuskElite]

Comment: @delboud I suppose you'd use `filter` for that.  It's like `where`, only you can write a function that returns true/false.  http://jsfiddle.net/k3JEz/2/